Ubuntu 22.04 Media Thumbnails not displayed in Nautilus anymore
Recently, not quite sure since when, Thumbnails in Nautilus for videos and music stopped being displayed as usual, most likely due to an update?
I have done this:
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer

And this:

Press Ctrl+H, enter into the folder named .cache. Then enter in the
folder thumbnails. Delete everything in there. Restart your PC.

Thumbnails for videos are back, but my local mp3 music files are still not showing thumbnails for album art which I have added manually over time using Ear Tag.
What else can I try?

For anyone else having this issue, ensure you have videos installed.
sudo apt install totem

